# Use array and file for same loop in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, csv

So my bash script have two options of running. With no argument, it reads a csv file stored in a fixed path. CSV will just contain one column of numbers

```
Numbers
1
2
3
4
```

The script can also receive a comma-separated list of numbers (e.g. bash script.sh `1,2,3,4`). That is, my script should treat these two kinds of input same. However, my current script has two functions for each input.

For CSV file, I pass in with `<<<`:

```
{
    read number_header
    while read number
    do
        do-something $number
    done
} <<< "$CSV_FILE"
```

And for the number list argument, I use for loop:

```
for number in "${numbers[@]}"
do
    do-something $number
done
```

I tried passing in the array `numbers` with `<<<`, but only the first argument is read. Is there a clean way of treating two inputs (array and csv file) with one loop?

Comment: Does `<<< "$CSV_FILE"` really work? I would have expected that to need to be `< "$CSV_FILE"` or `read` should just get the filename.

Comment: Huh interesting. My original script has `<` but my `<<<` also seems to work in my test script? I am not too sure what the difference between the two would be though.

Comment: `<` reads from a file `<<<` is a here-string. It passes the string as the standard input. See `cat <<<foo` vs. `cat <foo` in an empty directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to convert CSV file to a BASH array:

```
if [[ -n "$CSV_FILE" ]]; then
   # read whole csv file into an array
   numbers=( $(<"$CSV_FILE") )
   # remove first element for header
   unset numbers[0]
fi
```

Then have common code to handle array later as shown in question:

```
for number in "${numbers[@]}"; do
    do-something $number
done
```

Comment: Or: `numbers=( $(sed 1d "$CSV_FILE") )` and no need to unset anything.

Comment: This works safely for this specific non-CSV CSV input file. It isn't a generally safe solution though.

Comment: Yes it is not generic. Only because OP wrote it is a one number column input file I suggested this.

Comment: Right, I just needed to add the caveat so it was there.